# Positioning situation in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I've been trying to fix this problem, but I have no idea. I know before I've asked about origin, but I don't really know how to fix this.

[image]

red dot = coordinates x-y

yellow dot = origin used in spritebatch.draw

origin = new vector(img.width/2, img.height/2);

position = new rectangle(400, 200, img.width, img.height);

center_x = position.center.x
center_Y= position.center.y

I noticed that even though I placed the origin when using spritebatch.draw, the positioning is still done from the 0,0 origin instead of the Yellow dot. How can I change this? I noticed it when I check both the center for Y and X on the position rectangle and compared it with the actual coordinates. The center was higher than the coordinates its self. I want it so that the center coordinates are the same from the position's X & Y. Example, I assign 200 for X and 200 fro Y in the position rectangle. When I go check the center of that rectangle, I want it to be 200 on both X and Y. Also, I'm using a rectangle for positioning cause I'm also testing out so collision stuff.

An example would be nice, thanks in advance

Comment: ignore the green bar lol

Comment: `spriteBatch.Draw(img, img_rec, null, Color.White, 0, origin_Img, SpriteEffects.None, 0);` this is the spritebatch.draw I was talking about

Comment: Just going to comment one thing about your code here; don't use short and unintelligible variable names like "img", "img_rec" and "origin_img". Give them proper names like "image", "sourceRectangle", "origin", etc. And don't use underscore either. C# uses camelCase and/or PascalCase syntax.

Comment: I normally don't name them like that. It was just wanted like a quick name for testing purposes. I use underscore cause at night if I use camel notation it becomes a bit hard to read specially if I'm writing for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing to positioning a rectangle, use a Vector2 to positioning instead:

```
  Vector2 origin = new Vector2(img.Width, img.Height) * 0.5f;
  Vector2 pos = new Vector2(400,200) + origin;
  spriteBatch.Draw(img, pos, null, Color.White, 0, origin, SpriteEffects.None, 0)
```

This works for sure.

EDIT:
      if you want to work with rectangles be sure that origin is related to the texture size.

```
  Rectangle bounds = new (400,200, img.Width, img.Height);
  Vector2 origin = new Vector2(img.Width, img.Height) * 0.5f;
  spriteBatch.Draw(img, bounds, null, Color.White, 0, origin, SpriteEffects.None, 0)

  This works too. 

  The position of the yellow dot will be (400,200)
  if you don't use origin, the red dot position will be (400,200)
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't see position on our example of spriteBatch. try using it with all properties.

```
SpriteBatch.Draw (Texture2D, ImgPosition, ImgRect, ImgColor, ImgRotate, ImgOrigin, Scale, SpriteEffects, Layer)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to draw a sprite setting its `Origin` in its center you're doing it right. Your yellow dot is at position (400, 200) and the dot in the screenshot is reasonably in that position, considering the screen dimension of 800x480. But if you want that the upperleft corner of your sprite has that position you need to change your `Draw` call.

When specifying the `Origin`, try using `Vector2` position instead of `Rectangle` for the second parameter of `Draw` to set the positin of your sprite.

Specify `Vector2` Position and Origin:

```
origin = newVector2(img.Width, img.Heigth) / 2;
pos = new Vector2(400, 200) + origin;
spriteBatch.Draw(img, pos, null, Color.White, 0, origin, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

Or use only the position `Rectangle`:

```
posRect = new Rectangle(400, 200, img.Width, img.Heigth);
spriteBatch.Draw(img, posRect, Color.White);
```

Comment: thanks. Similar to a past answer, but any answer is very welcomed in my book. I did like you explanation.

Comment: the thing is that I'm trying to test collision while testing this. And collision without a rectangle is very complicated. Maybe I didn't explain my problem correctly and I apologize for that. Basically I want the coordinates to be where the yellow dot instead of where the red dot is.  If I tried what most of you recommended the center is way off from where I need it to be